# Eclipse link how to query

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I started to work with eclipse link and from what I read in the net the eclipse link is some kind  of JPA implementation and you are not working directly with DB code when you are using eclipse link you are working with objects.

My question is what is this if not DB command?

```
Query q = em
        .createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName = :firstName AND p.lastName = :lastName");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [JPQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language). You can find more [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL)

Comment: The difference is that once you create your model (entities and relations between them), JPA will handle the SQL query generation based on the JPQL you provide. For example, once you defined a many to one relationship between entities Order and Customer, a JPQL query would look like "SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.customer.code = :cust_code" (hint: you don't have to define the joins every time you query, dot notation will do that for you). JPA and JPQL is far more than that but I hope you got a point.

Answer (score 0):

Its JPA query equivalent to `SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE FIRSTNAME='Stefan' and LASTNAME='Strooves';` further you need to set value for parameters.

```
Query q = em
    .createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName = :firstName AND 
                                               p.lastName = :lastName");
q.setParameter("firstName", "Stefan");
q.setParameter("lastName", "Strooves");
List<Person> resultList = q.getResultList();
```

Result list contains all the `Person` entities matched with query.

Comment: Sure I understand that but what is the difference between DB query to use the eclipse link objects ?

Comment: @StefanStrooves Learn JPA.